# Cast a run-time Dictionary<K, V> that comes as a generic type argument into its proper compile-time type

Tags: c#

Consider this:

```
public void ReadEachItemInTheDictionary<V>(V value)
{
  // I know that value is a dictionary
  // where the key and value are scalars
  // or primitive types or value types
  if (value.GetType().IsGenericType && 
       value.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == 
              typeof(Dictionary<,>))
  {
    // I know the System.Type of each type
    // argument of the dictionary

    var keyType = value.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

    var valueType = value.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[1];

    // Now, I want to do something like this:
    foreach(var keyValuePair in value)
    {
        // However, since at compile-time, there
        // is no guarantee for the compiler that 
        // value is indeed an IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<,>>
        // that code won't work, obviously.

        // I want to basically get a handle on the
        // data


        // I feel horrible. I should know this. And
        // there was a time I did. Just feeling ashamed now.
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**

Looking at the two answers I have received, I feel compelled to highlight my problem again:

I only have the type parameter names of the `key` and `value` of the dictionary. Oh, I suddenly got the answer. Wait, I am posting it.

**Update again**

No, wait. What am I doing? Still unresolved.

Comment: You should be able to enumerate on the values without having compile-time type safety, essentially treating the values as type `object`. Another option is to use the DLR `dynamic` keyword to do some binding at runtime if that's a possibility for you.

Comment: Thank you, Chris. I always forget. Please add the `dynamic` part as an answer and I will mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This smells like abuse of generics, but anyway:

Put the foreach loop into a separate method that has the proper generic type parameters (probably, they will be the same that the dictionary has).

```
static void Read<TKey, TValue(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict) {
 foreach(var keyValuePair in dict) { }
}
```

In that method you can use that dictionary like normal.

Call that method using reflection (`MakeGenericMethod`), or like this:

```
Read((dynamic)value);
```

You can not leave all the dictionary processing code statically typed. Only the call must be dynamic.

Comment: Thing is: I only know the `System.Type`s of the type arguments of the dictionary. I don't know what the types are. They could be anything. I just know their System.Types. I want a strongly typed dictionary reference as the compile-time type.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 that's impossible inside of ReadEachItemInTheDictionary. But with the trick shown here you can have it in Read. Why doesn't this work for you?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I could have used the dynamic type to read it. Thanks much.

Answer (score 3):

Generic `Dictionary<>` implements non-generic `IDictionary`, so you can cast and use it:

```
var dict = value as IDictionary;
foreach (var item in dict)
{
    var entry = (DictionaryEntry)item;
    // use entry.Key and entry.Value
}
```

Comment: Nice. But I also wanted the exact type argument types behaving like I had known them at compile-time.

Comment: This unfortunately seems to be not possible, you can't use Reflection at runtime to make compile time type casting. But you can use `dynamic` to fool yourself: `dynamic key = entry.Key; key.SomePropertyHere...`

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest an approach that is more cooperative with the type system. Your problem really boils down to the fact that `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` doesn't implement a non-generic interface, otherwise you could simply cast the dictionary to `IEnumerable<NonGenericKeyValuePair>`. However, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` does support the non-generic [IDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which has individual `Keys` and `Values` collections, so you can do this:

```
var dict = (IDictionary)input;
for each (var key in dict.Keys) {
    var value = dict[key];
}
```

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right. Why didn't I think of that. Thank you very much. :-)

Answer (score 0):

How forgetful of me. `MakeGenericType` is my friend.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx